# OSMC Direct Title Playing Via SSH Command

Tags: ssh, osmc

I'm trying to control my OSMC via SSH. I'm sending commands via an SSH link with a Crestron Control system and want to play files directly from that interface as well as stop play and any other available transport controls and menu Navigation controls via SSH or some other Ethernet control protocol. Would love to add CEC control too at some point. But I'll cross that bridge later.

Comment: fancy seeing you here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the xbmc-send command. For example to make the video window the active window you would enter this:

```
xbmc-send --action="ActivateWindow(Videos)"
```

A list of the built in actions can be found [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/List_of_built-in_functions).

I could not find how to get the currently playing title using xbmc, but there is a [JSON-RPC API](http://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API), some examples can be found [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API/Examples), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654466/how-to-get-currently-playing-item-in-xbmc) explains how to get the currently playing title using it.

To access the API endpoint you will need to make sure HTTP control is enabled. To do this:

- select the **system** menu
- then the **settings** menu
- then **services**
- then **Web Server**
- ensure that **Allow remote control via HTTP** is checked and note the **Port** number

You will also need the IP address of your Pi.

from the command line enter the following:

```
curl --data-binary '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "Player.GetItem",
    "params": {
        "properties": [
            "title",
            "album",
            "artist",
            "season",
            "episode",
            "duration",
            "showtitle",
            "tvshowid",
            "thumbnail",
            "file",
            "fanart",
            "streamdetails"
        ],
        "playerid": 1
    },
    "id": "VideoGetItem"
}' -H 'content-type: application/json;' http://IP address:port number/jsonrpc
```

replacing "IP Address" and "port number" in the above with yours.